# Change marker image when a button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, marker, jquery-gmap2

I'm using gMap2, and I'd like to change the marker image from "marker1.png" to "marker2.png" **when a button is clicked**. I have the following code:

```
// Declare the marker
var customMarker = "img/marker1.png";

// Initialize the map
$('#map').gMap({

    address: "Paris, France, cité Nollez 3.",
    zoom: 12,
    markers:[
        {
            address: "Paris, France, cité Nollez 3.",
            html: "_address"
        }
    ],
    icon: {
        image: customMarker, 
        iconsize: [61, 63],
        iconanchor: [12, 46]
    }

});

// Change marker image on button click
$("button").click(function(){
    customMarker === "img/marker2.png";
});
```

Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hrLga/

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I believe you need to call gMap again after customMarker i changed.

Comment: @Adam submit your comment as an answer so the question can be marked resolved and you get credit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to call gMap again after customMarker is changed.